# How to get URL string into PHP variable

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's start with an example:

So requested URL would be: www.domain.com/product/hdd/samsung

I want to have a rewrite rule to get index.php and save everything after www.domain.com into php variable. So, substituted page would be for example www.domain.com/index.php?query=product/hdd/samsung. But I'am unable to write correct rule.

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [NC,L]
```

The code above isn't working. I want to use the query in PHP code in the index.php:

```
if(isset($_GET["query"] )) {
   $query=$_GET["query"];
}
```

I find out, there is possibility to get `$query` via `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` instead of `mod_rewrite`, am I right?

For my PHP application is variable `$query` critical, because it's used for loading templates.

**Questions**:
What solution would you recomand me? To use `$_SERVER` variable or `mod_rewrite`?
If `mod_rewrite`, how to write correct `RewriteRule`?

Thank you

Comment: That rule looks fine to me. Can you test some simpler rules to verify the rewrite rule module is applied and running properly?

Comment: Make sure you have `RewriteEngine on` somewhere.

Comment: Rewrite Engine is working properly (It's on). If I use the rule above, I get 404 Error. I'am testing it on localhost (wamp server).

Comment: The best rule I have been able to write is: RewriteRule /(.*) index.php?query=$1 [NC,L], but I only get string after the second slash (if there is second slash or I get 404 error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [NC,L]
```

If your site is not in your server's root dir, change `RewriteBase` to `/some/subdir/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, Its working! But it removes parameters, e.g www.domain.com/a/b/c?sort=price. (I get index.php?query=a/b/c).  I need somehow store whole string (sort=price). The best solution would be to get index.php?query=a/b/c&sort=price. I actually just need one parameter (sort). Is it even possible?

Comment: I'm quite sure I did something wrong, because I couldn't get the `?sort=price` with the rewrite rule. It's like it never existed. 

So I thought about parsing that part with php directly. Using lafor's code, you request the correct php file, and inside that file, you get the sort part with this code: http://pastebin.com/vLMNSCyK . I hope it helps.